# Javascript Function duplicating itself after every run

Tags: javascript, function, leaflet

When I run my function in the desired way, opening the context menu and then clicking the button, I can see my desired result the first time. Every time after that, it runs it always one time more. So the second time, I get the success message twice, the third three times, and so on.

This is for a Leaflet Maps project, by the way.

Also, I need to have the functions on the main map.on function, to get the coordinates of the click.

```
map.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('context-menu').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('context-menu').style.left = e.originalEvent.x + 'px';
    document.getElementById('context-menu').style.top = e.originalEvent.y + 'px';

    function copyCoordinates() {
        var lat = e.latlng.lat;
        var lng = e.latlng.lng;
        var zoom = map.getZoom();
        var params = 'lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lng + '&zoom=' + zoom;
        var newUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?' + params;
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(newUrl);
        toastr.success('Copied coordinates to clipboard!', {timeOut: 5000})
        document.getElementById('context-menu').style.display = 'none';
        
    }
    document.getElementById('copyCoordinates').addEventListener('click', copyCoordinates);

    function copyCoordinatesFormatted() {
        var lat = Math.floor(e.latlng.lat);
        var lng = Math.floor(e.latlng.lng);
        var formatted = '"lat": ' + lat + ',\n  "lng": ' + lng + ',';
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(formatted);
        toastr.success('Copied coordinates to clipboard!', {timeOut: 5000})
        var flag = true;
        document.getElementById('context-menu').style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('copyMarker').addEventListener('click', copyCoordinatesFormatted);
});
```

I tried adding flags, but that didn't work.

Comment: The `.addEventListener()` function does exactly what its name says: it **adds** an event listener, without affecting the status of previously-added listeners. Thus every time the "contextmenu" event fires, more event listeners are added to the "copyCoordinates" and "copyMarker" elements.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using onclick rather then EventListeners.

```
    document.getElementById('copyCoordinates').onclick = copyCoordinates;
```

Thanks for the help!